# Qual é a diferença entre verbos como "me tornou" e "tornou-me"

Tags: gramática, verbos, pronomes, colocação-pronominal

Estou um pouquinho confuso acerca de como distinguir entre "me tornou" e "tornou-me", e também quais as diferenças entre as duas.

Seria bom se me ajudassem. Podem-me explicar essa diferença?

Comment: Você poderá encontrar informações úteis procurando por [próclise](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pronominal#Pr%C3%B3clise) e [ênclise](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloca%C3%A7%C3%A3o_pronominal#%C3%8Anclise).

Comment: Uma referência mais completa sobre este tópico é o [cap. 65 da Gramática da Gulbenkian](http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/wochwel/documents/Cl%C3%ADticos_Gram%C3%A1tica%20do%20Portugu%C3%AAs_Gulbenkian.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Em diferentes situações, o pronome (neste caso "me") pode ter de vir antes do verbo (senão usa-se "tornou-me"). Ver exemplos ajuda:

*Frase "normal":*
O vestido **tornou-me** feliz. O rapaz **tornou-se** um bom atleta. O Natal **torna-nos** melhores pessoas.

O "me" vem antes do verbo "tornou" apenas se a frase tiver:

1. *uma oração subordinada:* Encontrei um vestido **que me tornou** feliz. Conheço um rapaz **que se tornou** um bom atleta. O Natal é uma época **que nos torna** melhores pessoas.
2. *um advérbio de negação:* O vestido **não me tornou** feliz. O rapaz **nunca se tornou** um bom atleta. O Natal **não nos torna** melhores pessoas.
3. *uma pergunta iniciada por "que/quem/o quê/quando":* Que vestido **me tornou** feliz? Quem **se tornou** um bom atleta? Quando é que **nos tornamos** melhores pessoas?

Este site tem todos os diferentes casos: [Próclise, mesóclise e ênclise](https://www.infoescola.com/portugues/proclise-mesoclise-e-enclise/), mas os 3 que eu listei são os mais comuns.

(Let me know if you prefer this translated into English)

Comment: Muito fixe esta resposta!

Comment: obrigada! foi assim que aprendi também, por isso espero que ajude

Comment: Gostei tb. Vai ajudar